# Use routes for mulitlevel folders in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to use CodeIgniter to route to sub folders. My current folder setup is like this with my routes line to access my owners controller. The url i am access is www.site.com/owners/home

```
controllers /
        login.php
        owners /
                home.php
                profile.php
        students /
                home.php
                profile.php

$route['owners'] = "owners/home";
```

I would like to put the owners and students into a seperate folder, to group them, but access them through the same url and not show the users folder. I was hoping the route below would get me where I wanted.

```
controllers /
        login.php
        users / 
                owners /
                        home.php
                        profile.php
                students /
                        home.php
                        profile.php

$route['users/owners'] = "owners/home";
```

Comment: No, you cannot set the folders like that, it will not work. Rename your controllers like this `owners_home.php` and `students_home.php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['owners'] = "users/owners";    
$route['owners/(:any)'] = "users/owners/$1";
```

You got it back to front the part to the left is the bit in the URL -> the part to the right is the part that defines where the path will go in the controllers.

The second statement might be necessary to ensure controllers methods still work - depends on your routes.php file as my customised install is now heavily modified!